# How to delete repeating records and leave just one using R?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a large data frame with 16 columns (variables) and I need a way to reduce its size (number of records) according to a condition.  Wondering if anyone here knows a way to do it in R.

I need to clean the file based on this.  It has the following columns: "Employee ID", "Year", "Month", and "Termination".  Variable "Termed" is coded as 0=Active and 1=Termed.  So, it has many rows per "Employee ID" (one for each year and month they have been working in the company until there is a value of "1" in the "Termination" column or there is just no more data for that specific "Employee ID" (all its values in the "Termination" column are "0"), in which case I need to keep just that last record.

In summary I need to clean the file in a way that I just have, for those who were terminated (Termination =1), the record in which Termination = 1 for each Employee ID AND the last record for those who were never terminated (all the values in the Termination variable are "0").

Is there a way to do this in R?  I appreciate your help.

Comment: You describe your problem really good, but honestly, this is a really simple and basic problem. Check whatever R-introduction course on Youtube.

Comment: Please provide an example dataset.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get to Rome. For data.frames this should do:

```
# Generate some dummy data
employee_data <- data.frame(employee_id = c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10)), year = 1990, month = rep(1:10,2), termination = c(rep(0,10),rep(0,9),1))

# Order entries according to wishes
employee_data <- employee_data[with(employee_data, order(employee_id, -termination, -year, -month)), ]

# Select first rows per employee_id
employee_data[! duplicated(employee_data$employee_id), ]
   employee_id year month termination
10           1 1990    10           0
20           2 1990    10           1
```

The sorting algorithms are quite fast so this should work for very large data sets as well.

Not strictly related: I would use the data.table package. The syntax is nicer and it works better with large data.